# opencart 2.2 Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME

Tags: javascript, php, mime-types, opencart2.x

When I try to put an image in the product description the following error occurs:

> "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME".

This happens only when I search the images inside a folder. Images that are in the root works normally.

When I choose an image inside some folder, the image opens in another tab and it is not added in the content of the description

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! To fix the /admin/view/javascript/common.js file.

Look for a line // `$ ('# modal-image a.thumbnail'). In ('click', function (e) {`

inside function

```
// Replace the summernotes image manager
('Summernote'). Each (function () {
```

Replacement of

```
$ ('# Modal-image a.thumbnail'). On ('click', function (e) {
E.preventDefault ();
$ (Element) .summernote ('insertImage', $ (this) .attr ('href'));
$ ('# Modal-image'). Modal ('hide');
});
```

by

```
$ ('# Modal-image'). Delegate ('a.thumbnail', 'click', function (e) {
E.preventDefault ();
$ (Element) .summernote ('insertImage', $ (this) .attr ('href'));
$ ('# Modal-image'). Modal ('hide');
});
```